# Sharepoint for Project Management

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

Out of the box what are my options in share point for creating a project management website?
I need to be able to create and manage multiple projects and be able to view the status of each. There does to appear to be a template for this or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

There are few templates available for you to start-up with:

[Look at Project Tracking section](http://www.microsoft.com/government/en-us/campaigns/Pages/SharePoint-Templates.aspx)

I personally like one from Bright Work:

[SharePoint Project Management Templates](http://www.brightwork.com/templates/project_management_templates.htm#project-standard), they also have free versions [Free SharePoint Project Management Templates](http://www.brightwork.com/resources/free_sharepoint_project_management_template.asp?event=6#.Uygvzvm1ZbU)

You can also think of implementing [Project Server](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/project/project-portfolio-management-for-the-enterprise-project-server-FX103802061.aspx) (which is actually SharePoint based) for project management.

PS: I don't work for Bright Work and it is not a marketing strategy !

Comment: but out of the box is there any available. I do not have access to add templates.

Comment: Well, SharePoint is a Platform.. If you think that way, there is nothing available OOB, you need to utilize the OOB features to make one!

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2010 there is no built in project management template.

There are pieces and parts you can string together and arrange into a solution (Task lists, custom lists you can build for risk management, change requests, staff management, etc). As mentioned you can find complete project template solutions, you can also find project management specific type building-blocks (web parts, other custom pieces) as well (Bamboo comes to mind, there are others).

Regarding your question about managing multiple projects and seeing the status of each, here is an interesting blog series about how to use the Query string url parameter to simplify the creation of (what I think) you are trying to accomplish:

[Query String URLs are Magical (Part 2 of 4)](http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=daba3a3b-c338-41d8-bf52-cd897d000cf3&ID=70&Web=dbb90e85-b54c-49f4-8e97-6d8258116ca0)

This is not a complete solution, as the author say, but a piece of the puzzle and should get you going in the right direction.

> She says
>
> "In this post, I’ll get more into a really cool example of what can be
>   accomplished with query strings, and taking it to the next level.
>
> In this example, we have a site with
>
> - Project List
> - Tasks
> - Issues
> - Change History
> - Status Reports
>
> The point is
>   that all of these lists have something in common… the project.  The
>   main project list can have multiple items associated with it, from
>   each of the other lists.  We want to display all of these items on the
>   same page in SharePoint.  So, we create a “Project ID” field, which
>   will be used as the common thread.  We’ll start with the built in ID
>   field in the main project list, and in each of the other lists, create
>   a number field called “ProjID”."

Answer (score 0):

We have a solution for rolling up multiple task lists, either within the same site or across multiple sites, into a single view. Better yet, it does not require you to add a template or web part to the system. If you can upload a file to a document library you can get things going.

It's built on HTML5 so it will run on desktops, laptops, tablets, phablets and more... anything with a modern HTML5 browser on it.

Here is the help page with a minimum and full installation guide and features described.

https://www.intelligantt.com/SPProject1/help/index.html

Note-- I do work for TeamDirection, but I also believe this is an excellent solution.